# Calculating the Gini Coefficient from LIS data (in Stata)

Tags: stata

I need to calculate the Gini coefficient from disposable personal income data at LIS.  According to a LIS training document, the Stata code to do this is:

```
    di "** INCOME DISTRIBUTION II – Exercise 13 **"
    program define bottop
    qui sum ey [w=hweight*d4]
    replace ey = .01*r(mean) if ey<.01*r(mean)
    qui sum dpi [w=hweight*d4], de
    replace ey = (10*r(p50)/(d4^.5)) if dpi>10*r(p50)
    end
    foreach file in $us00h $fi00h {
    display "`file'"
    use hweight d4 dpi if (!mi(dpi) & !(dpi==0)) using "`file'", clear
    gen ey=dpi/(d4^0.5)
    bottop
    ineqdeco ey [w=hweight*d4]
    }
```

I have simply copied and pasted this code from the training document.  The snippets

```
    qui sum ey [w=hweight*d4]
    replace ey=0.01*r(mean) if ey<0.01*r(mean)
```

and

```
    qui sum dpi [w=hweight*d4], de
    replace ey=(10*r(p50)/(d4^0.5)) if dpi>10*r(p50)
```

are bottom and top coding, respectively.

When I tried to run this code, the variable hweight was not found.  Does anyone know what the new name of hweight is at LIS?  Or can anyone suggest how I might otherwise overcome this impasse?

I'm familiar with stata, but the sophistication of this code is beyond my ken.

Much appreciated.

Comment: ask this on statalist. With some luck, Stephen Jenkins, one of the authors of the underlying `ineqdeco`, could reply. You have to RTFM the study documentation to find out what the variables are. `hweight` is probably the household weight. I don't see why you want to spoil good data with top and bottom coding, though. An odd exercise, overall.

Comment: What is [LIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIS)?

Comment: @whuber Luxembourg Income Study

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a second-best solution.  However, the census of population provides income by brackets.  If you are willing to do that, you can get the counts for every bracket.  Have a top-coded bracket for the last one.  Use the median income value within each bracket.  Then you can directly apply the formula for the Gini coefficient.  It is a second best because it is an approximation for the individaul-level data.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [varaiable definition list](http://www.lisdatacenter.org/wp-content/uploads/our-lis-documentation-variables-definition.xlsx) at the [LIS Documentation page](http://www.lisdatacenter.org/our-data/lis-database/documentation/), it looks like the variable is now called `HWGT`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try the fastgini command:

http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2007-02/msg00524.html

```
ssc install fastgini
fastgini income
return list
```

this should give you the gini for the variable income.

This package also allows for weights. Type

```
help fastgini
```

for more information